# Find the values of $\alpha, \beta$

Tags: probability, integration

Let $X$ be a random variable with the following pdf:

$$\displaystyle f(x) = \alpha \cdot e^{-x^2- \beta x}, x \in \mathbb{R} .$$

Also, $E[X]=-0.5$ . Well the problem is straightforward except that I am not able to integrate this function. How can I evaluate this integral?

Comment: Hint : complete the square when integrating

Comment: Oh yeah why didn't I think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach rather than integration:

Recall that the pdf for normal distribution when $\mu=-\frac12$ is

\begin{align}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp \left(-\frac{(x^2-x+\frac14)}{2\sigma^2} \right)\\
&=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp \left(-\frac{1}{8\sigma^2} \right)\exp \left(\frac{-x^2+x}{2\sigma^2} \right)\\\end{align}

Hence $2\sigma^2=1$, and hence $\alpha=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left( -\frac14\right)$ and $\beta=-1$.